# else statement issue powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, function, if-statement

Everything in this script I wrote works with `if` and `ifelse` statements but not the `else` statements. Could someone please review the following and help me figure out why? The desired outcome is if I type `aconda`, a conda environment launches, `aconda -d` deactivates conda and alters the path, `aconda -a` activates conda and alters the path . Is there a way to specify the outcome of no parameter?

```html
function aconda {
  param(    
  [Alias('d')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Deactivate')]
  [switch] $Deactivate
  ,
  [Alias('a')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Activate')]
  [switch] $Activate
  ,
  [Alias("h")]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='help')]
  [switch] $help
  )
  
  if ($Activate) {
      $Environment = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
      foreach ($path in ($Environment).Split(";"))
      {
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
      }
      $env:PATH = $Environment
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda activate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  } 
  elseif ($Deactivate) 
  {
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
      $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
                  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'    
  }
  elseif ($help)
   { Write-Output "
  -a    activate conda
  -d    deactivate conda
  -?    Help. This is the same as not typing any options"
   }
  
  else { . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**
This works, but still ignores the else statement:

```html
function aconda {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Activate')]
  param( 
  [Alias('d')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Deactivate')]
  [switch] $Deactivate
  ,
  [Alias('a')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Activate')]
  [switch] $Activate
  ,
  [Alias("h")]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='help')]
  [switch] $help
  
  )
    $noInput = !$Deactivate -and !$Activate

  if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Activate') -or $noInput ) {
      $Environment = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
      foreach ($path in ($Environment).Split(";"))
      {
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
      }
      $env:PATH = $Environment
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda activate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  } 
  elseif ($Deactivate) 
  {
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
      $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
                  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'    
  }
  elseif ($help)
   { Write-Output "
  -a    activate conda
  -d    deactivate conda
  -?    Help. This is the same as not typing any options"
   }
  
  else { . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  }

}
```

This does not, the only difference being `if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Activate') -or $noInput )` vs `elseif ($noInput) { . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3' }`:

```html
function aconda {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Activate')]
  param( 
  [Alias('d')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Deactivate')]
  [switch] $Deactivate
  ,
  [Alias('a')]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Activate')]
  [switch] $Activate
  ,
  [Alias("h")]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='help')]
  [switch] $help
  
  )
    $noInput = !$Deactivate -and !$Activate

  if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Activate') ) {
      $Environment = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
      foreach ($path in ($Environment).Split(";"))
      {
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
          if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\")
          {
          $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
          }
      }
      $env:PATH = $Environment
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda activate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  } 
  elseif ($Deactivate) 
  {
      . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
      $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
                  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'    
  }
  elseif ($help)
   { Write-Output "
  -a    activate conda
  -d    deactivate conda
  -?    Help. This is the same as not typing any options"
   }
  
  elseif ($noInput) { . C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
  }

}
```

Comment: your if cascade looks like it otta work. have you tried commenting out the current content of each block and adding a  `Write-Host` with the name of the current block to see what happens with each possible value? ///// also, the `switch` structure is a handy alternative for an `if/elseif/else` cascade. it has a `default` section for "no matches found" ... [*grin*]

Comment: I can't post a full answer right now but essentially your function is invalid. It produces an error `aconda : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` If you don't see that, your `$ErrorActionPreference` might be set to `SilentlyContinue`, which is bad for debugging.  To fix your function, you need to identify a default parameter set so Powershell know what to do if it can't meet the requirements of any of the 3 parameter set defined. This can be accomplished by adding `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Activate')]` before the `param` block of your func.

Comment: Everything should work relatively fine after that... except if you start doing `aconda -a:$false`, which would end up in the `Else` block too because of the way your code is structured. to account for that, you'd need to replace the `if($Activate)` by `if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Activate')` and then, in your condition, you deal with `$Activate` but know that it could be set to `$false` if you did `aconda -a:$false`, which is a very valid way of working with switch parameters.

Comment: May be stating the obvious, but after adding the cmdletbinding per @Sage's instruction it's probably easier to just make a final param to be the default e.g. `"[Parameter(ParameterSetName='default')]
  [switch] $default"`

Comment: @MikeAnthony I would personally not do it that way because while you might not have to differentiate to determine whether you want to do the activate or default block (which my solution implies), you would get that extra switch parameter `default` showing up in the auto completion.

Comment: @SagePourpre That fixed the error message about perimeters but the else statement still doesn't work

Comment: see the recent edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Answering your question

Switch parameters are inherently $False, unless the user specifies that param.  Since you want to do an operation if both switch params are false, you can add a check for that condition.

```
$noInput = !$Deactivate -and !$Activate
#...
  elseif ($help -or $noInput){
  #your Code here
}
```

**Note**: You will need to remove your CmdletParamSet attributes to use this technique.

If you want to ensure your users aren't running the function with both `-Activate -Deactivate` specified, then just add a check to see if both are true and if so `Write-Error "You may only specify one activation selection"`

##### Easier Alternative

Or better yet, change the switch statements to `[switch]$ActivationStatus` and remove the second switch, then users will use the function like this:

```
aconda -ActivationStatus $true

aconda -ActivationStatus $false
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the `help` statement, but if I define the last `else` statement as `elseif ($noInput)` , I still get no response. I'm not sure why the final statement is ignored

Comment: see the recent edit

Comment: Frankly I think you're making this much harder on yourself than you need to. Try the easier alternative approach I provided.

Comment: To use that elseif, just change the `$noInput` code to this.  Since you're declaring the input as a SwitchParameter, we have access to the helpful `IsPresent` autoproperty which we can use.  `  $noInput = !$Deactivate.IsPresent -and !$Activate.IsPresent`